# C# Excel Format the color of multiple cells

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

Hello i try to format multiple cells with different colors. So the range changes when there are multiple objects in a list.

Here is my Code:

```
        public void writeExcelFile(SPpowerPlant powerPlant, string sqlServer, string database)
        {

            //Path to template
            String tenplate = @"C:\Users\AAN\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\PowerPlants\Powerplants\bin\Debug\PROJEKTSTATUS_GESAMT_neues_Layout_template.xlsm";

            //open Excel (programm)
            Excel.Application excelApplication = new Excel.Application();

#if DEBUG
            excelApplication.Visible = true;
            excelApplication.DisplayAlerts = true;
#else
                excelApplication.Visible = false; 
                excelApplication.DisplayAlerts = false;
#endif

            //Open a Excel File
            Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Add(tenplate);
            Excel._Worksheet excelSheet = excelWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
            SPpowerPlantList powerPlantList = loadProjectsAndComponentsFromSqlServer(sqlServer, database, Convert.ToDateTime(powerPlant.timestamp), powerPlant.note);

            //Lists for the Excel Sheet
            List<String> projectName = new List<String>();  //1
            List<String> phase = new List<String>();        //2
            List<String> countryshort = new List<String>(); //3
            List<double> projectShareWeb = new List<double>();  //4
            List<double> mwWeb = new List<double>();        //5
            List<double> projectProgress = new List<double>();  //6
            List<double> mwDeveloped = new List<double>();  //7
            List<double> yearlyYieldOfWholeProject = new List<double>();    //8
            List<double> capexWholeProject = new List<double>();    //9
            List<double> equityAmount = new List<double>(); //10
            List<double> equityIrr = new List<double>();    //11
            List<String> cod = new List<String>();      //12
            List<String> projectmanager = new List<string>();   //13   
            List<String> changes = new List<string>();  //14
            List<String> technology = new List<string>();   //15
            List<String> countrylong = new List<string>();  //16
            List<String> state = new List<string>();    //17

            //to get the values into the lists from a powerplant
            foreach (SPpowerPlant powerPlantItem in powerPlantList)
            {

                if (powerPlantItem.phase == "Phase 6")
                {
                    ////Format the Header row to make it Bold and blue
                    excelSheet.get_Range("B4", "O4").Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
                    //excelSheet.get_Range("A1", "B1").Font.Bold = true;
                }

                projectName.Add(powerPlantItem.projectName); //1
                phase.Add(powerPlantItem.phase);    //2
                countryshort.Add(powerPlantItem.country);   //3
                projectShareWeb.Add(powerPlantItem.projectShareWeb);    //4
                mwWeb.Add(powerPlantItem.mwWeb);    //5
                projectProgress.Add(powerPlantItem.projectProgress);    //6
                mwDeveloped.Add(powerPlantItem.mwDeveloped);    //7
                foreach (SPeconomicIndicator economicIndicatoritem in powerPlantItem.economicIndicators)
                {
                    yearlyYieldOfWholeProject.Add(economicIndicatoritem.yearlyYieldOfWholeProject); //8
                    capexWholeProject.Add(economicIndicatoritem.capexWholeProject); //9
                    equityAmount.Add(economicIndicatoritem.equityAmount);   //10
                    equityIrr.Add(economicIndicatoritem.equityIrr); //11
                }
                cod.Add(powerPlantItem.cod.Value.Year.ToString()); //12
                projectmanager.Add(powerPlantItem.projectManager); //13
                changes.Add("???"); //14
                technology.Add(powerPlantItem.technology); //15
                countrylong.Add(powerPlantItem.country); //16
                state.Add(powerPlantItem.state); //17

            }

            //adding it to the excel sheet
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < powerPlantList.Count; i++)
            {

                excelSheet.Cells[i + 4, 2] = projectName[i]; //1
                excelSheet.Cells[i + 4, 3] = phase[i];  //2
                excelSheet.Cells[i + 4, 4] = countryshort[i];   //3
                excelSheet.Cells[i + 4, 5] = projectShareWeb[i];    //4
                excelSheet.Cells[i + 4, 6] = mwWeb[i];  //5
                excelSheet.Cells[i + 4, 7] = projectProgress[i];    //6
                excelSheet.Cells[i + 4, 8] = mwDeveloped[i]; //7
                excelSheet.Cells[i + 4, 9] = yearlyYieldOfWholeProject[i]; //8
                excelSheet.Cells[i + 4, 10] = capexWholeProject[i]; //9
                excelSheet.Cells[i + 4, 11] = equityAmount[i]; //10
                excelSheet.Cells[i + 4, 12] = equityIrr[i]; //11
                excelSheet.Cells[i + 4, 13] = cod[i]; //12
                excelSheet.Cells[i + 4, 14] = projectmanager[i]; //13
                excelSheet.Cells[i + 4, 15] = changes[i]; //14;
                excelSheet.Cells[i + 4, 16] = technology[i]; //15
                excelSheet.Cells[i + 4, 17] = countrylong[i]; //16
                excelSheet.Cells[i + 4, 18] = state[i]; //17

            }

            //Save the excel workbook under a different name
            excelWorkbook.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\AAN\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\PowerPlants\Powerplants\bin\Debug\PROJEKTSTATUS_GESAMT_neues_Layout.xlsm", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

            excelApplication.Quit();

        }
```

When i try it whit a singe range it works as expectet but when there are multiple objects with Phase 6 only on row gets the new color. So how can i change the rows on the fly? So every value with Phase 6 gets the format i want?

So any help would be great and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is quite lengthy and most of it does not really relate to your question.  It would be better to extract the pertinent issue as a generic code sample, so that others can copy the code into their machines and then try to debug it.

The main issue is that you are not assigning a color to a range of cells anywhere, except initially while assigning the range B4:O4.  So each time you encounter Phase 6, that same range gets assigned the color, but not the the row you are about to populate.

You could try some variation of this (although it is a bit clunky, and may not correspond to the exact ranges you are looking for):

```
    List<string> powerPlantList = new List<string>
    {
        "test",
        "blah",
        "phase 6",
        "foo",
        "bar",
        "phase 6"
    };

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Excel.Visible = true;
    Workbook wkbk = Excel.Workbooks.Add();
    Worksheet sheet = wkbk.ActiveSheet;


    int initialRow = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < powerPlantList.Count; i++)
    {
        string s = powerPlantList[i];
        string row = (i+ initialRow).ToString();
        if (s.Equals("phase 6"))
        {
            sheet.get_Range("B" + row, "O"+row).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
        // This is where you assign the color to the current row range

        }
        sheet.Cells[i + initialRow, 4] = s;

    }
```

You also seem to be overly complicating your approach to parsing each powerPlantItem.  You are better off just making a list of the type `SPowerPlant` and then looping through each powerPlant  to directly populate the worksheet.  You probably don't need to create a series of lists to store the properties of each powerPlant.

Comment: thx for your answer this works really great and i tried it with the SPowerPlant but didnt get i to work but it dosent matter becouse i try to get better in c# with excel. So its not to bad becouse on my work-place they never will see that.